# Using ord() recursively in Python

Tags: python, recursion, ord

I need to convert a string to numbers using a recursive function and I'm a little confused about how to go around the base and recursive cases. I have the following code but I'm not sure where it's going wrong.

```
def string_to_num(s):
    if s == "":
        return []
    else:
        return ord(s[0]) + string_to_num(ord(s[1:]))
```

Comment: why `return []` ?

Comment: Also, how exactly do you want to convert the string? Do you want its Unicode? Its numeric value if it was an integer? Something else? I am not sure I get it.

Comment: I want its Unicode value

Comment: @lilai then check out user1740577's answer below, it should solve your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need assume `string_to_num(ord(s[1:]))` back ord as `string` so you don't need `ord(s[1:])` you need `string_to_num(s[1:])` and you need back string then use `+`, you can change your code like below:

```
>>> def string_to_num(s):
...    if s == '':
...        return ''
...    return f'{ord(s[0])}' + string_to_num(s[1:])

>>> string_to_num('abc')
'979899'
```

And if you want as list you can use this:

```
>>> def string_to_num(s):
...    if s == '':
...        return []
...    return [ord(s[0])] + string_to_num(s[1:])

>>> string_to_num('abc')
[97, 98, 99]
```

Comment: A question, is slicing faster here than just passing say the index (e.g. `def string_to_num(s,i)`...`i+=1`...`return ord(s[i])..`? I am not certain about it, and I tried to do a look up for it but I couldn't find anything clear, but my gut tells me it might be faster (since returning one element at every point, and not creating new lists?)

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle you are right and we can solve faster way but we need solve OP problem and question and OP want **`Using ord() recursively in Python`**

Comment: I agree, I just asked out of curiosity haha. Cheers buddy.

Comment: @ZaidAlShattle haha ;)